# How about a few badges as a rememberance to a Winter Bash?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request, winter-bash

How about a few badges as a rememberance to a Winter Bash?

Such as:

- Bronze: Get a normal hat on a site. (awarded once per Winter Bash per site, not once per hat)
- Bronze: Get a secret hat on a site. (awarded once per Winter Bash per site, not once per hat)
- Silver: (**Collector**) Get ten hats on a site.
- Gold: Get all normal hats on a site.
- Gold: Win the winter bash. The badge will be awarded to all sites you have at least 1 hat.

Hats will disappear, but then you have at least a few badges as a rememberance and a symbol to the nice Winter Bash.

Answer (score 7):

Hats are for low-level achievements. Badges are usually for something more and long-lasting contributions to the site. I don't think we should award a badge for every hat you achieve. What is the purpose for a hat then? This would also skew the badge count, which is somewhat an indicator of the level of participation on a site.

If you want to have a badge, make one badge for every time you participate in a Winterbash (like the Caucus badge for elections). I think that might even be too much.

Comment: I did not mean one badge per hat. I just meant one badge per Winterbash, so at most 5 badges in total. (Its more likely to be 4 or less)

Comment: I even think that is too much. How does this contribute to the overall purpose of badges?

Answer (score 4):

I would very much **dislike this**. As much as I am a badge-hunter I absolutely **hate** hate hate rewards of any kind that you can get only at one point in time but are kept track of forever.

The hats and badges are a nice gamification gimmick. But if I start using StackExchange intensely in mid January and get badge after badge (because I like the badge gamification effect) there will be no way for me to get the `Winterbash` badge. Following the same logic I would instantly remove the `Precognitive` if I could.

Too many games do this and it bothers me there already. Don't make the mistake here as well. You could/can never get 100% this way if you missed the one point in the past.